# Имею недопонимание в передаче параметров/результатов в/из функции на ARM

Tags: функции, arm

Доброго всем времени суток.
Имею дизасм кода под ARM. И отсутствие понимания организации передачи через стек.
(ну т.е. вроде понятно все...но вот при дизасме, временами, не могу "вкурить" куда у них чего предполагается положить/взять)

Собственно первый момент недопонимания 00007B44...00007B48.
В регистры R2 и R1, являющиеся парамтрами
вызываемой далее функции попадает SP+1 и SP+2
Какая из переменных var_XX или аргументов arg_4/pGraphBuffer
соответствует SP? Потому что далее в функции sub_7AB2
будет LDRH  R3, [R1] и  LDRB  R4, [R2] а загрузки в [SP] (+1,2,3)
от начала функции и до вызова  BL  sub_7AB2 не наблюдается, соответственно не понятно что там будет на момент вызова функции

```
ROM:00007B0A sub_7B0A
ROM:00007B0A
ROM:00007B0A
ROM:00007B0A var_2F          = -0x2F
ROM:00007B0A var_2E          = -0x2E
ROM:00007B0A var_2C          = -0x2C
ROM:00007B0A var_28          = -0x28
ROM:00007B0A var_24          = -0x24
ROM:00007B0A var_20          = -0x20
ROM:00007B0A var_1C          = -0x1C
ROM:00007B0A var_18          = -0x18
ROM:00007B0A pGraphBuffer    =  0
ROM:00007B0A arg_4           =  4
ROM:00007B0A
ROM:00007B0A                 PUSH      {R4-R7,LR}
ROM:00007B0C                 SUB       SP, SP, #0x1C
... ... .... ; пропускаем не существенный для нашего вопроса код. 
ROM:00007B3E loc_7B3E
ROM:00007B3E                 LDR       R0, [SP,#0x30+arg_4]
ROM:00007B40                 CMP       R0, #1
ROM:00007B42                 BNE       loc_7B52
ROM:00007B44                 MOV       R2, SP
ROM:00007B46                 ADDS      R2, #1
ROM:00007B48                 ADDS      R1, R2, #1
ROM:00007B4A                 LDR       R0, [SP,#0x30+pGraphBuffer]
ROM:00007B4C                 BL        sub_7AB2
```

Здесь во-первых та самая вызываемая функция, и вопрос с R1,R2.
И опять же тот же самый R2, но уже в смысле, а откуда предполагается 
в вызывающей процедуре чиать то что туда (в [R2]) положили (см. адрес 7AD6)

```
ROM:00007AB2 sub_7AB2
ROM:00007AB2
ROM:00007AB2 localPGrBuffer  = -0x18
ROM:00007AB2
ROM:00007AB2                 PUSH      {R4-R7,LR}
ROM:00007AB4                 SUB       SP, SP, #4
ROM:00007AB6                 STR       R0, [SP,#0x18+localPGrBuffer]
ROM:00007AB8                 LDR       R7, =0x7FFF
ROM:00007ABA                 LDR       R0, =off_FC1E6030
ROM:00007ABC                 LDR       R5, [R0] ; word_FC1F8E9C[]
ROM:00007ABE loc_7ABE
ROM:00007ABE                 LDRH      R3, [R1]       ; Не понятно что тут при входе !!!
ROM:00007AC0                 LDR       R0, [SP,#0x18+localPGrBuffer]
ROM:00007AC2                 ADDS      R6, R3, R0
ROM:00007AC4                 LDRB      R4, [R2]     ; Не понятно что тут при входе !!!
... ... ... ... ...
ROM:00007AD6                 STRB      R4, [R2]  ; из возвращаемых значений имеем только 
                                                 ; 0/FF в R0 и вот этот самый STRB R4,[R2]
                                                 ; напомню в R2, перед вызовом положили SP+1
```

Comment: Разобрался...долбаная IDA в одних функциях она интерпретирует смещение переменных так, что переменная с самым большим минусом соответствует SP, а в других нет(в смысле не соответствует. более того пишет LDR       R0, [SP,#0x30+arg_4] а в реальности там 0x3C+arg_4...ну если следовать логике "соответствия"). Из-за этого не мог никак поймать закономерность...пока в ручную не подизасмил хекс коды операций с регистром SP в разных функциях....

Comment: можно узнать, почему вы не хотите оформить как ответ?

Comment: потому что туплю....:) не до конца разобрался как тут что работает...все аврал...аврал...

Comment: Все правильно ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался...долбаная IDA в одних функциях она интерпретирует смещение переменных так, что переменная с самым большим минусом соответствует SP, а в других нет(в смысле не соответствует. более того пишет LDR R0, [SP,#0x30+arg_4] а в реальности там 0x3C+arg_4...ну если следовать логике "соответствия"). Из-за этого не мог никак поймать закономерность...пока в ручную не подизасмил хекс коды операций с регистром SP в разных функциях....

P.S. Foggy Finder, Вот так? Я правильно понял, про оформить как ответ?